# REST api for apache spark

Tags: android, python, apache-spark, tensorflow, livy

I have a .py file that contains a machine learning with apache spark using mongodb and i want to connect the results of my code to an android application, 
is this a way to do that with a REST api , 
I heared about tensorflow and livy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choices for building a REST api:

1. Use `flask` package (`pip install flask`). It helps you to quickly
   build a server that can run the python code and is accessible via
   web. See [official website](http://flask.pocoo.org/). For small projects, this is my
   recommendation.
2. If you are planning on running a TensorFlow model to do the inference, see [tensorflow-serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/).
3. Apache can run python (legacy, 2.7).
4. Livy is highly oriented for Spark. See [official website](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/).

Good luck!